# CA web form taking very long to respond for job completed

Tags: central-administration, performance

We are using SharePoint 2013 on-premise. In recent few months we found the CA is very slow in respond. For example, I just create a simply team site. It shows me the "Working on it...  This shouldn't take long." screen for over 5 minutes. I check the SQL server and found the job is actually completed. I can browse the new site collection as well. However the "Working on it..." screen is showing forever so I close the tab.

I think it is not a SQL performance issue but what can I check? I am the only SharePoint admin so I am sure no other operation is running beside the default timer jobs.